# self.__class__ in parent class' method is missing arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass, class-method, python-class

A package I am using contains the class A. I want my new class B to inherit from this class. Minimal example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def my_method(self):
        return self.__class__(name = self.name)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.value = value
        super().__init__(name)

B_instance = B(value = 5, name = "Bob")
B_instance.my_method()
```

Calling the parent's method on the child throws:

```
File ..., line 5, in my_method
    return self.__class__(name = self.name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

How can I fix this without changing anything in class A? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If the only thing you need from `self` is its type, define a class method instead. `@classmethod def my_method(cls): return cls(name="Alice")`.

Comment: The problem, though, is that you've changed the signature of `B.__init__` in a way that is not compatible with how `A.my_method` will call it.

Comment: You'd have to overload my_method in B, because instantiating B requires more arguments than instantiating A does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A.my_method` assumes that `A` (or any subclass thereof) can be instantiated with a single argument. You broke that assumption by adding a required argument `value` to `B.__init__`. You'll need to make `value` the *second* parameter, and make it optional.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.value = value
```

Whether it is *useful* to use `A.my_method` to create an instance of `B` with `value=None` is another question.

---

Let's pretend you *could* change `A`. Then it would be better to design it to facilitate subclassing in the first place.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, **kwargs):
        # Note: passing an explicit name argument will
        # result in a TypeError on multiple arguments for
        # the keyword argument 'name'
        return cls(name="Alice", **kwargs)
```

Now you could define `B` as

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *, value, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value = value


a1 = A(name="Bob")
a2 = A.my_method()  # A(name="Alice")

b1 = B(name="Joe", value=5)
b2 = B.my_method(value=10)  # B(name="Alice", value=10)
```

This uses advice from https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ with regards to `__init__` (and by extension, alternate class-method constructors):

- use keyword arguments when calling
- only handle your own parameters explicitly
- accept all unexpected keyword arguments to pass on to an ancestor class